# limit the blur effect

Tags: ios, swift

After figuring out how to add/remove the blur effect I created a button that adds and one that removes the blur effect, but, if I click more times on the blur button it blures the image again and again

Here is the addBlur func

```
@IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurView.frame = myImageView.bounds
        myImageView.addSubview(blurView)
    }
```

And here is the removeBlur func

```
@IBAction func remove(sender: AnyObject) {
        for view in self.myImageView.subviews{
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    }
```

I would like it blur the image once, and also to find out if it is possible to blur it not that much, but let's say 20-30% of the currect effect.

I tried a lot of things to disable the add button once pressed but can't find any working one

Here is one of the many examples I found

```
addButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

P.S. I read like 5-6 guides about blurring and couldn't find any information about limiting it to like 20-30%, that's why I'm asking here for help

Answer (score 0):

This project is a good way to go:

[GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

It uses the GPU to do the rendering so it's pretty fast and configurable.

To disable the button use:

```
addButton.enabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Since native blur effects are pretty limited you can maybe use [this library](https://github.com/szk-atmosphere/SABlurImageView), in the documentation it is said that :

> If you want to use 0.0 to 1.0 parameter

```
let imageView = SABlurImageView(image: image)
imageView.configrationForBlurAnimation(100)
imageView?.blur(0.5)
```

So this might be what you are looking for,

Hope this will help you !